# Vetor de Structs para função

Tags: c

Estou com um problema pra passar um vetor de `structs` para uma função que verifica se um código inteiro digitado pelo usuário já foi usado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define TAM 10000

struct bebida
{
  char nome[30];
  float teor_alcoolico;
  float valor_unitario;
};

struct cadastro
{
  int codigo;
  char nome[60];
  char local[60];
  int data;
  int quantidade_de_ingressos;
  float valor_da_entrada;
  float custo_da_ornanizacao;
  struct bebida pinga;
};

int i, j;

int busca(int *evento, int valor, int tamanho) //FUNCAO VERIFICA SE O CODIGO ESTA NO VETOR
{
  int igual = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
  {
    if (*evento[i].codigo == valor)
    {
      igual++; //SE IGUAL FOR ZERO QUER DIZER QUE NAO ESTA NO VETOR
    }
  }

  return igual;
}

void menu()
{
  printf("=========MENU=======\n");
  printf("Entre com: \n");
  printf("(1) Cadastrar evento\n");
  printf("(2) Pesquisar evento\n");
  printf("(3) Ingressos vendidos\n");
  printf("(4) Exibir resultado por evento\n");
  printf("(5) Exibir resultado geral\n");
  printf("(6) Sair\n");
  printf("===========================\n\n");
}

int main(void)
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
  int opcao, indicador, digitos, contem;
  int tamanho;
  struct cadastro evento[1000];
  for (i = 0; i < 999; i++)
  {
    evento[i].codigo = 0; //INICIAR COM 0(ZERO) PRA NAO FAZER COMPARACAO COM LIXO E SE O CODIGO FOR 0 VAI SAIR
  }
  menu();
  scanf("%d", &opcao);
  switch (opcao)
  {
    case 1: //CADASTRAR EVENTO
    {
      tamanho = 1;

      for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
      {
        tamanho++;
        printf("Entre com o código de cadastro\n");
        scanf("%d", &digitos);
        if (digitos == 0)
        {
          break;
        }
        else
        {
          do
          {
            contem = busca(&evento[i].codigo, digitos, tamanho);
            if (contem == 0)
            {
              evento[i].codigo = digitos;
            }
            else if (contem != 0)
            {
              printf("Código já cadastrado por favor insira novamente o codigo para cadastro\n");
              scanf("%d", &digitos);
            }

          } while (contem != 0);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: estou com um problema pra passar um vetor de structs para uma função que verifica se um codigo inteiro digitado pelo usuario ja foi usado. alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifique a assinatura da sua função para que ela receba um vetor de estruturas:

```
int busca(struct cadastro evento[], int valor, int tamanho)
```

Em seguida, modifique a chamada dessa função para que um vetor de estruturas seja passado à ela:

```
contem = busca(evento, digitos, tamanho);
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado mesmo!!!!